# is it possible to open sqlite Db in android which is encrypted using syste.data.Sqlite (.net namespace)?

Tags: c#, android, sqlite

Hi i had encrypted sql lite database as

```
DataSource = "Data Source=" + txt_FilePath.Text;
SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(DataSource);
cnn.Open();
cnn.ChangePassword(txt_Password.Text);
label2.Text = "Password Encrypted Successfully";
cnn.Close();
```

Now i want to decrypt the database in android, in .net we pass connection string as datasource ="";password=; how to pass the password connection string in android

Answer (score 0):

Encryption is not built into SQLite itself.  There are third parties that offer variations it, including both the developers of SQLite ([SEE](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/see.html)) and the System.Data.SQLite developer (Robert Simpson).  He [said](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/p/2536/9856.aspx#9856) he deliberately made the System.Data.SQLite version non-crossplatform to avoid competing with the SQLite developers.

EDIT: There is a libre library (3-clause BSD) called SQLCipher that adds AES encryption to SQLite.  It says it supports .NET and Java, and there is a very [new project](https://guardianproject.info/code/sqlcipher/) bringng it to to Android.  They say it's designed to be similar to the built in Android SQLite API.

Comment: oh.. god non-crossplatform.. should i go only with SEE or do i have anything else?

Comment: @Bhuvan, I found a library you can try.  I haven't used it.